# $Q(m^{1/4})$ for $m$ non-square is degree 4 extension over $Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This is an exercise in Marcus. I think what Marcus means is that $m$ contains at least an odd power of prime.

$Q(m^{1/4})/Q$ is degree 4 extension where $m$ is not a square.

For $m=-4$, $Q(m^{1/4})=Q(i)$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Does he mean that $m$ contains at least an odd power of prime or he means that $m>0$?

Comment: Well, $-4$ is certainly not a square in $\mathbb Z$...

Comment: Which exercise is it ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is chapter 4, Exercise 13's before part a). It seems that it is obvious that $Q(m^{1/4})/Q$ is degree 4. I used Eisenstein to conclude that any $m=p^{4k+a}l,(p,l)=1,a=1,3$ with $l$ arbitrary integer. $Q(m^{1/4})/Q$ is degree 4. For $a=3$, I consider $1/m$ and multiply it by appropriate integer to reduce to $a=1$ case. I think I am right for $m$ not "square" by containing a prime factor of odd power unless I have made dumb mistake.

Comment: @lhf $-n^2$ for any $n$ does not work. However for $m=-2$, this should work as I did not get any quadratic polynomial for $\frac{(1+i)}{2^{1/4}}$ where I picked $(-1)^{1/4}=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$. .

Comment: Yes, this is certainly another typo in the text - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287092/typo-in-marcus-textitnumber-fields?rq=1) for a similar post. I would say, Marcus means:" Assume that $|m|$ is not a square".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh In that case, thanks a lot for point out this.